# Mongodb: Converting numeric string to number

Tags: mongodb

How can we convert a numeric string to number in Mongodb?

Actual Problem: 
Collection: `try`
Two Sample documents stored in `try` collection:

```
{
  _id: "1"
  testField: 150
}


{
  _id: "A"
  testField: 140
}
```

I want to filter out the `_id` field in the project phase for further processing in group phase. The query below is working fine but I need better solution for it like using `type` or any other method.

```
db.try.aggregate([{$match: {"_id":{$in:["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]}}}, {$group:{"_id":0, total: {$sum:"$testField"}}}])
```

Comment: This query will give all `_id` db.try.find({"_id":{$type:2}}).  As '_id' will be always string, it is not meaningful query. Can you provide more details please? Furthermore you can follow link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

Comment: @Vishwas what's the benefit of this query? This will not differentiate between "1" and "A".

Comment: @CodeCore you want to find numeric ids which were saved as string. Right?

Comment: Also, you are using `$in` for 1-9. Do you have only 9 records(as _id is unique) ?

Comment: @Vishwas type:2 will return all the documents as _id is string only.

Comment: @dev Yes I am trying to find numeric ids which were saved as string. Yes,  at present there are only 2 records for testing.

Comment: @CodeCore solution by Karthik will work for any number of digit.

Comment: @CodeCore that is what I mentioned in my comment already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex in this case:

```
db.try.aggregate([{$match: {"_id":
{$in:[/\d+/]}}}, 
{$group:{"_id":0, total: {$sum:"$testField"}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [**MapReduce**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) where in your map function you can check whether an _id contains a number:

**Sample documents:**

```
db.try.insert([
    {
      _id: "1",
      testField: 150
    },
    {
      _id: "2",
      testField: 150
    },
    {
      _id: "A",
      testField: 140
    },
    {
      _id: "B",
      testField: 140
    }
]);
```

**MapReduce**:

```
var map = function(){
    var numeric_id = !isNaN(this._id) ? "numeric" : "non_numeric";
    emit(numeric_id, this.testField); 
};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
};

db.try.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    { out: "try_totals" }
);
```

**Result**:

```
db.try_totals.find()

/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "non_numeric",
    "value" : 280
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "numeric",
    "value" : 300
}
```